# MS SQL Server 2016 - Always On Node-2 Stuck In Resolving State

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups, clustering, failover

For testing the Always On structure; we suddenly shut down the machine on which Node-1 was running. So we wanted to see that Node-2 turns primary. However, Node-2 was stuck in resolving mode.

> **3 machines:**
>
> *First machine runs Active Directory.*
>
> *Second machine runs Node-1 (instance-1).*
>
> *Third machine runs Node-2 (instance-2).*

---

> **Availability group properties:**
>
> *Cluster type: windows server failover cluster*
>
> *Database level health detection is checked.*

---

Availability replicas:

> **Instance-1 (Node-1) properties:**
>
> *Role: primary*
>
> *Availability mode: synchronous commit*
>
> *Failover mode: manual*
>
> *Connections in primary role: allow all connections*
>
> *Readable secondary: yes*
>
> *Seeding mode: manual*
>
> *Session timeout: 10 seconds*
>
> *Endpoint URL: TCP://somehost:port*

---

> **Instance-2 (Node-2) properties:**
>
> *Role: secondary*
>
> *Availability mode: synchronous commit*
>
> *Failover mode: manual*
>
> *Connections in primary role: allow all connections*
>
> *Readable secondary: yes*
>
> *Seeding mode: automatic*
>
> *Session timeout: 10 seconds*
>
> *Endpoint URL: TCP://somehost:port (same port with instance-1)*

---

> **Failover cluster manager properties:**
>
> *Roles: 1 role is running and owner ise node-1.*
>
> *Nodes: 2 nodes are up.*
>
> *Disks: 1 cluster disk is online, owner node is node-2, capacity is
> 10GB.*
>
> *Networks: 1 network is up, cluster use: cluster and client.*

How can I fix it?

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read correctly, your failover mode is set to "manual". In this case, SQL will not trigger a failover by itself.

If you are expecting node 2 to be promoted as primary automatically when node 1 goes down, then you will need to change the failover mode to "automatic" and then, that should do it.